# Inequality like $AB \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2n}A^2 + \frac{n}{2\epsilon}B^2$

Tags: inequality

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.11741v2.pdf) on page 18 there is an inequality that I cannot prove. I will only look at the term with $K$, since the term with $b$ follows analogously I think.

So we have, using $L_{\sigma}M>0$ to ease the notation:

$$
L_\sigma M \sum_{i=1}^n \Big(1 + \frac{L_\sigma M}{n}\Big)^{n-i} \int_{\frac{i-1}{n}}^{\frac{i}{n}} ||K(t) - K_{i-1}^{(n)}||\;dt \leq \frac{\epsilon L_\sigma M}{2n} \sum_{i=1}^n \Big(1 + \frac{L_\sigma M}{n}\Big)^{2(n-1)} \\+ \frac{n L_\sigma M}{2\epsilon} \sum_{i=1}^n \Big( \int_{\frac{i-1}{n}}^{\frac{i}{n}} ||K(t) - K_{i-1}^{(n)}||\;dt\Big)^2,
$$

for any $\epsilon>0$ and for $n\geq 1$.

Now I think that this does not make use of any of the properties of $K$ or anything else, so I think I need to prove the identiy (for all $1\leq i \leq n$)

$$
A_iB_i \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2n} A_i^2 + \frac{n}{2\epsilon} B_i^2,
$$

where $A_i=\Big(1 + \frac{L_\sigma M}{n}\Big)^{n-i}$ and $B_i = \int_{\frac{i-1}{n}}^{\frac{i}{n}}||K(t) - K_{i-1}^{(n)}||\;dt$.

Now from above I know that $A_i = \Big(1 + \frac{L_\sigma M}{n}\Big)^{n-i} \geq 1$, I also know that $K^{(n)}\to K$, but I don't know how to use that.

Something I noticed which might be useful:

$$
A_iB_i \leq A_i^2 + B_i^2
$$

Comment: It's AM/GM: $a^2+b^2\ge2ab$ for suitable $a$, $b$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A_i, B_i \in \mathbb{R}$, then this is literally Young inequality for products:

$$ab \leq \frac{a^2}{2 \varepsilon} + \frac{\varepsilon b^2}{2} $$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality_for_products

Comment: I had not heard of that one. I'll try to prove it and add it to my arsenal.

Comment: for a proof it suffices to observe $\frac{a^2+b^2}{2} \geq ab$ and pick $a = a'/\sqrt{\varepsilon}, b = \sqrt{\varepsilon} b'$ , so all in all, calling it "Young inequality" is a bit rich ;)

Comment: I like to call it the Peter-Paul inequality:-)